# Hard query for booking application with multiple resources

Tags: postgresql

There is a structure of related tables(resources) of the application.

Company (has many branches)

Branch (Has many services and masters)

Service

Master

Events  (belongs to master and service)

Each service has its duration

Each master is busy on some service and can have personal events, such as day offs or vacations.

Each master has his lunch time:

[image]

All they are events, so the event can be recurring and one-time.
The events table contains the data of busyness of the master.
So this is events table structure:

[image]

resource_type each time is Master (1)
Since each service has a duration, the event related with a service (not personal event) which is non-recurring event and has its own start and end date and time.
Recurring type can be:

[image]

Recurring numeric values can be:

For every week: 1-7

For every month: 1-31

For every year: a float number like this: 3.18 (from left of dot is a month, from right - day)

And there is no numeric value for every day, working day and weekend day, as they dont need.

So the inserting to the table  are ready, but now I started to face a real problem for the following: query all free masters and their available time slots for given service.
There are rules to keep:

1. Master has his lunch times
2. Master has events (recurring and non-recurring)

So I have no idea how to implement that query and actually no idea how should the algorithm be?
So if I want to reserve a service at X branch of Y company, the system should offer masters of that branch with their free time slots, depending on the service duration. Master may have personal events, such as day-offs (recurring=1, type=6) or each Monday at 12:00 may report to the managers about his income, which takes some minutes (recurring=1, type=2, numeric_value=1)

Can someone help me with this giant problem?